# how to set value in datasource of angular material

Tags: angular

I want to set value of a key in datasource.
I have two table in db one has order in which order color is stored in key and i want to show it's value , and values are stored in list table with key.

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<order>();
this.httpClient.get('/api/getorders').subscribe(res => {
   this.dataSource.data = res as order[];
});
```

then i am getting order from db ,and in this order color is in key form
and its value is in other table, where i want to display value insted of key.

```
for (let x = 0; x <= dataSource.length; x++ ) {
  for(var color in product.colors) {
    allProductsBykey[color] = product.colors[color].key.value;
    if (dataSource[x].color === product.colors[color].key) {
       var map = new Map();
       map.set(dataSource[x].color, product.colors[color].name);
       map.get(dataSource[x].color);
    }
  }
}
```

In datasource i want updated color as value not key

Comment: your question is not clear... if you make a stackblitz which shows what is wrong and also share what you're looking for, the community can help.

Comment: after set value to key i want to update this value in datasource and show in ui.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of writting second loop you do write this code.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="color">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Color </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.color}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

## Example

https://stackblitz.com/angular/dexlbavpqvm?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.ts